# About usage of will

Tags: grammar

Do you think this sentence is wrong?

- If you will go there, I will go there too maybe.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/will?s=t

The will have following menaings.

3. am (is, are, etc.) expected or required to
4. may be expected or supposed to

Q1. So, I think the sentence is correct. but i'm not sure.
What do you think about it?

Q2. Should I use the definite article in the title?

About usage of will vs. About the usage of will

Which one is more suitable for the title?

Comment: "Will" has a will of its own, and how it is interpreted is highly dependent on context.

Comment: So? We can't just say the sentence is correct or wrong, right?

Comment: The sentence is technically correct, but not particularly idiomatic.  The specific meaning is highly dependent on context and verbal tone.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional sentences type 1 there are 2 clauses: if clause (if + simple present) and main clause (simple future).
so I think we don't need to put "will" in the if clause.
If you go there, I will go there too maybe.
If you say "If you will go there, I will go there too", the sentence has a different meaning: If you are willing to go there, I am willing to go there too

Comment: I understand what you mean.How about In this case? If you will go there on business, I will go there on business too maybe. Both you and me are not willing to go, but have to go, because of the need of the work. It maybe happens, it depends to the decision of the company.

Comment: If they're not willing to go, just say: "If you go there on business, I will go there too." or "If you have to go there on business, I will go there too maybe."

Comment: Thanks for your help. What you wrote is normal pattern and much easier to understand. I think the sentence is correct, although it is not the standard conditional sentence. Because it's not normal, no one will use it in real life.